# How do I restart an erlang process in a list?

Tags: list, erlang

I have a list construction like this:

```
[{Value, spawn_link(fun() -> worker(Value, self()) end)} || Value <- List]
```

So I have a list with values and each value is handed in its own process with the line above. If one worker dies, I want to restart it (with the same value). I have saved the Value in the same tupel as the new process as above. Can I do some list comprehension to determine if the process has died, and in that case, start a new?

Comment: Why not use OTP to supervise your workers ? It's great at it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use erlang:monitor/2 to watch for your processes:

```
List1 = [{Value, spawn_link(fun() -> worker(Value, self()) end)} || Value <- List],
List2 = [{Value, Pid, monitor(process, Pid)} || {Value, Pid} <- List1]
```

And then wait for messages for monitors, restart your processes if you need and update List2 with new pids and monitors.

To get more info about erlang:monitor/2 read appropriate man page.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a function that creates a process that monitors a `Pid` and executes a `Fun` when it dies, like so:

```
on_exit(Pid, Fun) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
                  Ref = monitor(process, Pid),
                  receive
                      {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          Fun(Why)
                  end
          end).
```

Now, you can use the `on_exit` function to create a function for creating processeses that will restart automatically when the process dies:

```
keep_alive(Fun) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Pid = spawn_link(Fun),
    on_exit(Pid, fun(Why) ->
                         io:format("Process died: ~p, restarting it~n", [Why]),
                         keep_alive(Fun) end),
    Pid.
```

With these little two functions, your work to create processes that will restart automatically is reduced to simply calling `keep_alive` in your list comprehension:

```
[{Value, keep_alive(fun() -> worker(Value, self()) end)} || Value <- List].
```

**P.S.:** These two little functions are presented almost exactly like this in chapter 13 of the book [Programming Erlang 2nd Edition](http://pragprog.com/book/jaerlang/programming-erlang), I only did some minor changes to better suit to your case.

Comment: It has race condition. When your process dies before `on_exit/2` spawns it's own monitoring process it will bring down process executing `keep_alive/1` so it will not do the work unless you set `trap_exit` flag which you don't mention at all.

Comment: Hi, @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil! Nice catch, man, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your home made supervisor, don't forget to set `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` otherwise it will die at the same time one child die, and then all other children too:

```
1> F = fun() -> timer:sleep(2000) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.80484245>
2> F1 = fun() -> timer:sleep(2000), 1/0 end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.80484245>
3> S = fun() -> spawn_link(F), receive M-> M after 5000 -> no_message end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.80484245>
4> S1 = fun() -> spawn_link(F1), receive M-> M after 5000 -> no_message end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.80484245>
5> S1b = fun() -> process_flag(trap_exit, true), spawn_link(F1), receive M-> M after 5000 -> no_message end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.80484245>
6> self().
<0.40.0>
7> S().                                                                                   
no_message            
8> self().
<0.40.0>
9> S1().  

=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Mar-2014::06:46:27 ===
Error in process <0.49.0> with exit value: {badarith,[{erlang,'/',[1,0],[]}]}

** exception exit: badarith
     in operator  '/'/2
        called as 1 / 0
10> self().
<0.50.0>
11> S1b(). 

=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Mar-2014::06:46:39 ===
Error in process <0.53.0> with exit value: {badarith,[{erlang,'/',[1,0],[]}]}

{'EXIT',<0.53.0>,{badarith,[{erlang,'/',[1,0],[]}]}}
12> self().
<0.50.0>
13>
```

Unless you are doing this for education purpose, I recommend you to use the erlang otp supervisors, with a one_for_one restart strategy.